# Advantages of using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm comparing the render speed of the following two TodoMVC examples:

1. Backbone -
   http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/

   ```
   -> (on 1st loading) 14 requests  ❘  62.19KB transferred  ❘  2.01s (onload: 2.10s, DOMContentLoaded: 2.10s)

   -> (on cache loading) 14 requests  ❘  0B transferred  ❘  176ms (onload: 177ms, DOMContentLoaded: 175ms)
   ```
2. Backbone + RequireJS -
   http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/dependency-examples/backbone_require/

   ```
   -> (on 1st loading) 19 requests  ❘  73.95KB transferred  ❘  2.57s (onload: 2.57s, DOMContentLoaded: 1.14s)

   -> (on cache loading) 19 requests  ❘  0B transferred  ❘  224ms (onload: 244ms, DOMContentLoaded: 87ms)
   ```

Am I right to interpret it this way that using RequireJS would make `$(document).ready()` to be fired as early as possible, however the overall time required for the page to be done with rendering would actually become more lengthy?

Comment: Was this seen with async loading enabled, and on a browser that supports the async tag? I think that's often been the rationale for it (async was previously avoided due to the unpredictable order that things would load in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation.

However, it is worth noting that in the example given the [`r.js` optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) has not been run over the code so each of the individual modules is loaded separately so it does have that effect in this case.  However, if they **were** using an optimized version of the application all of the dependencies would be compiled into one file (unless specified otherwise) and the example would load only *four* files (five if the viewer was using a version of IE less than version 10).  I can't say for sure how much that would affect load times and `DOMContentLoaded`, but my *guess* is that it would lower the time for both of them.